# Highcharts data from MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I am trying to build the data for my Highcharts chart but I'm having trouble when a certain day has no rows.

I.e. I want a chart to show enquiries per day for the current week. If no enquiries were received on Wednesday, then that day is missing from my chart or the data from Thursday falls into Wednesday which is wrong, depending on what I do.

SQL I have:

```
$W = date('W');
    $Y = date('Y');
    $SQL = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(enquiries.dateCreated, '%a') AS name, COUNT(*) AS y
            FROM enquiries
            WHERE WEEK(enquiries.dateCreated, 1) = $W
            AND YEAR(enquiries.dateCreated) = $Y
            GROUP BY DAY(enquiries.dateCreated)";
    $result = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
    $result->execute();
    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And my current attempt to put it into an array which doesn't work:

```
$enquiries = $this->model->enquiriesTime();

    $dayData = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++) {
        if ($enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Mon' || $enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Tue' || $enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Wed' || $enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Thu' || $enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Fri') {
            $dayData[$i] = $enquiries[$i]['y'];
        } else {
            $dayData[$i] = '0';
        }
    }
```

When a day doesn't exist the 0 gets added to the end of the array and not index 2 (Wednesday) like it should, so Wednesday's results are actually Thursdays.

How can I get this to work properly?

---

Here is the JS:

```
function createActivityChart() {

$.ajax({
    url: ROOT + 'Ajax',
    data: {
        call: 'lists->enquiriesTime'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    success: function(returned) {
        $('#enquiriesChart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Weekly activity chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Mon',
                    'Tue',
                    'Wed',
                    'Thu',
                    'Fri'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: null,
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f}</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: returned
        });
    }
})
}
```

And the HTML container:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="gridData">
                        <div id="activityChart" style="min-width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you show the html view source, that will help to understand

Comment: Couldn't it come from the fact that you are adding the 0 value as a string in your else statement?

Comment: @m.pons The purpose of that is to add in the 0 that SQL misses.

Comment: I meant instead of having `$dayData[$i] = '0';` to have `$dayData[$i] = 0;`

Comment: @m.pons It makes no difference :(.

Comment: @imperium2335 it was a wild guess sorry. Could you confirm that the different scripts are the right ones. I probably missed something but the php and sql are based on days but the javascript has month in the xAxis.

Comment: @m.pons Sorry my mistake, that was for a different chart. I have updated the JS.

Comment: can this link help you get data from `mysql` in `highcharts` http://spjoshis.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-table.html

Comment: @Sameer No, this is just a basic tut about making a chart.

Comment: In general how your "returned" variable looks like?

Answer (score 0):

What I use to do to avoid your problem is create the highchart array with all 0 values, and then overwrite them. This way you make sure no data is left behind.

Comment: But how would you synchronize the SQL data with the array indexes?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but right now I'm leaving, but if you think about it, in a highchart you usually know what is the range of data, and how many values you're going to insert. You should provide a way to synchronize the SQL, according to the data you're going to show. When I've done it (with date), I knew prior to show anything, how many days there was before of retrieving the data

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have done it using this horrendous logic ladder:

```
for ($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            if ($enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Mon') {
                $dayData[$i] = $enquiries[$i]['y'];
            } else {
                $enquiriesI = array(array('name' => 'Mon', 'y' => 0));
                array_splice($enquiries, 0, 0, $enquiriesI);
                $dayData[$i] = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($i == 1) {
            if ($enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Tue') {
                $dayData[$i] = $enquiries[$i]['y'];
            } else {
                $enquiriesI = array(array('name' => 'Tue', 'y' => 0));
                array_splice($enquiries, 1, 0, $enquiriesI);
                $dayData[$i] = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($i == 2) {
            if ($enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Wed') {
                $dayData[$i] = $enquiries[$i]['y'];
            } else {
                $enquiriesI = array(array('name' => 'Wed', 'y' => 0));
                array_splice($enquiries, 2, 0, $enquiriesI);
                $dayData[$i] = 0;
            }
        }

        if ($i == 3) {
            if ($enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Thu') {
                $dayData[$i] = $enquiries[$i]['y'];
            } else {
                $enquiriesI = array(array('name' => 'Thu', 'y' => 0));
                array_splice($enquiries, 3, 0, $enquiriesI);
                $dayData[$i] = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($i == 4) {
            if ($enquiries[$i]['name'] == 'Fri') {
                $dayData[$i] = $enquiries[$i]['y'];
            } else {
                $enquiriesI = array(array('name' => 'Fri', 'y' => 0));
                array_splice($enquiries, 4, 0, $enquiriesI);
                $dayData[$i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

There must be a better way?

---

I have found that the above method works well for week days and the following method for days of the month:

```
public function parseMonthlyGraph($SQLResults) { // For days
    $dayData = array();
    $startDate = date('Y-m').'-01';
    $lastDay = date("t", strtotime($startDate));
    for ($i = 0; $i != 31; $i++) {
        if($i == $lastDay)
        {
            break;
        }
        $dayName = date('jS', strtotime($startDate . ' + '.$i.' days'));

        if ($SQLResults[$i]['name'] == $dayName) {
            $dayData[$i] = $SQLResults[$i]['y'];
            if (empty($SQLResults[$i + 1])) {
                $SQLResults[$i + 1]['name'] = date('jS', strtotime($startDate . ' + ' . $i+1 . +' days'));
                $SQLResults[$i + 1]['y'] = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $enquiriesI = array(array('name' => $dayName, 'y' => 0));
            array_splice($SQLResults, $i, 0, $enquiriesI);
            $dayData[$i] = 0;
        }
    }

    return $dayData;
}
```